# Best type of Joomla Extension for simple redirection function

Tags: javascript, php, mobile, joomla

I need to write an extension that will redirect users to the mobile version of a website using a JS library that tracks user-agents (extension is for the customers of a company that makes mobile websites).

The redirection script is just 4 lines of Javascript with a couple options, so my extension would need a config page.

Does this sound best as a **plugin, component or module?**

Looking through the developer docs I found that plugins get an **onBeforeRender event**. Would this be suitable?

Thanks

PS I think Joomla may offer it's own user agent sniffing but I have to use this external JS lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Components are like applications that appear in your content area such as a forum. Modules are small widgets that normally appear around your content such as a shoutbox. A plugin is used to manipulate the site bahaviour and can be triggered at specific times, such as before or after the content has loaded and so on.

There to simply answer you question, you will need a plugin for this:

http://docs.joomla.org/Portal:Plugin_Development

I do believe the `onBeforeRender` will be the one to use

Hope this helps

Comment: I went with `onBeforeCompileHead` in the end, ta

Answer (score 0):

This should be a plugin - a system plugin. It shouldn't take a lot of time to develop.

I have no idea why you were voted down for this question by the way. I didn't see anything wrong with you asked.

Answer (score -1):

I think it will be better if you develop a plugin as its going to have a very simple functionality.

Best of luck & do upload it on the JED when you are done developing!

Comment: @Lix - OP's question was what should i do? a component / module or plugin. So the answer was definitely correct as i did reply to him saying he should write a plugin!